Cancel process when loading data with Livewire
I have 1 modal where the modal uses 2 different processes, the case here is when I click on the second modal then the system will load data on the second modal, here I use chace so that the data load takes a long time only the first time to load, then it will not wait long because the data has been stored in chace. when I click on the first modal with large data and at that time I close the button on the modal when the data load has not been completed, at this point, I want to stop all the process load data in the first modal so that the data is not continued to be loaded, but the problem is when I click on the second modal, the data that has been stored in the cache will not immediately appear but instead appears loading. this is because the data load in the first modal has not been completed. what I want to ask is how do I stop all these processes when I close the button using Livewire?
I have done conditional if by giving true and false values but it still can't be done.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
